# File Name Path Bug

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm starting to program and I'm using Visual Studio. I have this simple program that some days ago worked, but after working with another project, it now returns me an error:

```
// Include file header
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <gif_lib.h>

void SaveDialogCreation(HWND hWnd)
{
    OPENFILENAMEA ofn;
    char szFileName[MAX_PATH] = "";

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text Files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0";
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = "txt";
    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT;

    // open save dialog
    if (GetSaveFileNameA(ofn))
    {
        gif_write(szFileName);
    }
}

//gif_write code function
bool gif_write(const char *fileName)
{
    // it using giflib_win library
    int error;
    // Open gif file
    GifFileType* gifFile = EGifOpenFileName(fileName, false, &error);
    // error while open gif file
    if (!gifFile) {
        std::cout << "EGifOpenFileName() failed - " << error << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    GifColorType colors[64];
    GifColorType* c = colors;
    int level[4] = { 0, 85, 170, 255 };
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; ++r) {
        for (int g = 0; g < 4; ++g) {
            for (int b = 0; b < 4; ++b, ++c) {
                c->Red = level[r];
                c->Green = level[g];
                c->Blue = level[b];
            }
        }
    }
    // Write pixel to gif
    GifByteType pix[16] = {
        0,  1,  2,  3,  // B
        0,  4,  8, 12,  // G
        0, 16, 32, 48,  // R
        0, 21, 42, 63,  // BK
    };

    gifFile->SWidth = 4;
    gifFile->SHeight = 4;
    gifFile->SColorResolution = 8;
    gifFile->SBackGroundColor = 0;
    gifFile->SColorMap = GifMakeMapObject(64, colors);

    SavedImage gifImage;
    gifImage.ImageDesc.Left = 0;
    gifImage.ImageDesc.Top = 0;
    gifImage.ImageDesc.Width = 4;
    gifImage.ImageDesc.Height = 4;
    gifImage.ImageDesc.Interlace = false;
    gifImage.ImageDesc.ColorMap = nullptr;
    gifImage.RasterBits = (GifByteType*)malloc(16);
    gifImage.ExtensionBlockCount = 0;
    gifImage.ExtensionBlocks = nullptr;
    memcpy(gifImage.RasterBits, pix, 16);

    GifMakeSavedImage(gifFile, &gifImage);

    if (EGifSpew(gifFile) == GIF_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "EGifSpew() failed - " << gifFile->Error << std::endl;
        EGifCloseFile(gifFile, &error);
        return false;
    }

    // Close gif file
    EGifCloseFile(gifFile, &error);
    return true;
}
```

I can compile it, but when I use the save dialog in `gif_write()`, it saves the gif file but has the first character in the filename.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `LPOPENFILENAMEA ofn` is just a pointer. You need to use `OPENFILENAMEA ofn` instead to actually provide the memory for the data structure. Refer to it like `ofn.lStructSize` rather than `ofn->lStructSize`, and when you call `GetSaveFileNameA` pass the address like `GetSaveFileNameA(&ofn)`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter It can compile but when open program and run save dialog. When run save dialog program is not responding and crash

Comment: @PhamDucDuy then you are still doing something else wrong. Please [edit] your question to show your updated code.

Answer (score -1):

> It can compile but crashed.

It's definite that there is a semantic problem with the code. A possible one is [OFN_EXPLORER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea) which Indicates that

> any customizations made to the Open or Save As dialog box. By default,
> the Open and Save As dialog boxes use the Explorer-style user
> interface regardless of whether this flag is set. This flag is
> necessary **only if** you provide a hook procedure or custom template,
> or set the OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT flag.

You could need [the example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/peertopeer/groupchat/vista/GroupChat.c#L1883).